# Connect WiFi Network via App

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, wifi

I actually create an app where the access to content should be restricted by the WiFi-network the user is connected to.

So is it possible to automatically login to a secured WiFi via App? I don't want to force the user to do it manually. It should be as simple as possible for the user.

Maybe there is a way to install a network profile for the device or something like that?

Any ideas about this?

THX

Comment: hi kev52, I have a similar problem , developping an app that could  (automatically) access to secure network in order to use some internet service inside the app. Did you resolve you problem? Is so, could give me some tips, please?

Comment: Hi kev52 and  doxsi Have you found any solution for this ? Looking for similar thing, I  need to connect a known Wifi network within app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to do this with the functions from the CaptiveNetwork framework...

Also you can create a network profile in Apple Configurator and then export them to a website. Then all your users need to do is click a link to that file that you can email them or put on your site or wherever...

[CaptiveNetwork reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: is it also possible to implement this profile as part of my app?

Comment: Technically you may be able to host a web server in your app and serve the profile that way... But it's easier to host it on a server and use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlToYourProfileOnTheWeb]`...