# How to Connect iOS Device with Public WiFi automatically in iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to connect my iOS device with Public WiFi through my App. How can i do? Please Help.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you achieve this?

Comment: @anoop4real Yes, Please follow the followings- Generate a .mobileConfig file using Apple Configurator with your Wifi SSID and password, install .mobileConfig file on iOS device, Then iOS device will connect with Wifi automatically.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to manage from with in App?

Comment: Yes, You may give a option for install config file from app bundle or from your sever.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. Also is there a way to detect available wifi without using private APIs

Answer (score 3):

I want to write a similar App before, and sadly the result is that you cannot connect WIFI without using private API.

You cannot even scan available WIFI nearby!

If you use private API,you cannot upload your App to App store.
I may give you some solution:

**Option 1:**

1. Save public WIFI location in your server DB
2. Use location to fetch WIFI data from DB
3. Give user WIFI password and let user connect WIFI for your APP.

**Option 2**
Using provisioning files

1. Save public WIFI location in your server DB
2. Use location to fetch WIFI data from server
3. When user want to connect your WIFI from server,guide user to a website(Safari).
4. Use this website to publishing **provisioning files**,this provisioning file contain WIFI SSID and password.
5. User choose to install this provisioning file,it will auto connect this WIFI

Comment: Thanks WenchenHuang!
Could you provide any link Or Sample to follow?

Answer (score 2):

Refer below link for solution that might be helpful...!

[Connect WiFi Network via App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066632/connect-wifi-network-via-app)

Check for WIFI connection availability

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];

NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(status == NotReachable) 
{
    //No internet
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
    //WiFi-- iOS 8 to Settings App and connect Wifi..!

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN) 
{
    //3G
}
```

Hope it helps you....!

Answer (score 1):

Generate a .mobileConfig file using Apple Configurator with your Wifi SSID and password, install .mobileConfig file on iOS device, Then iOS device will connect with Wifi automatically.

Comment: Can we archive build for ipa with .mobileConfig in order to distribute application over iTunes or enterprise. Or is it device specific feature? I want to connect my application with some specific wifi server. So if user go in range and have our app installed then it will connect with server automatically. Any suggestion?

Comment: You may have .mobileconfig in your app bundle or may install from a Server using a web URL.