# Connect Wifi in MS Universal windows app?

Tags: win-universal-app

We know an iOS app can connect to Wifi with [CaptiveNetwork](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/) reference. As described in some related post: [Connect WiFi Network via App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066632/connect-wifi-network-via-app).

Is there any similar library to help a Windows app to view exising wifi around and get connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There's the Windows.Devices.Wifi namespace. (Details here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.wifi.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 )
It offers Methods to list networks and a method called ConnectAsync() to connect. I once coded a sample here (it also covers other stuff):  https://github.com/DanielMeixner/w10demoking/blob/master/Windows10DemoKing/wifi.xaml.cs

The magic lines of code are

```
    using Windows.Devices.WiFi;
// create network adatper instance (see sample code in link above) ...


var nw = nwAdapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks.Where(y => y.Ssid.ToLower() == "myssid").FirstOrDefault(); 
await nwAdapter.ConnectAsync(nw, WiFiReconnectionKind.Automatic);
```